# Integral of $\frac{1}{x+\sin x}$

Tags: integration

I'm interested in determining the antiderivative of
$$\frac{1}{x+\sin x}$$
I'm also interested in its bounded integral form:
$$\int_A^B\frac{dx}{x+\sin x}$$
I've not been able to find anywhere to start. I thought it would be a trigonometric integral, but it doesn't quite fit.

Comment: The integral is non-elementary. Are you looking for a series approximation?

Comment: When in doubt, check [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F%28x+%2B+sin+x%29).

Comment: A series approximation would be great. So for non elementary integrals should I just take the Taylor series?